# Should I use NumPy array if I don't know the end number of elements in my database?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, hdf5

I am working at sattelite monitoring database which will be often updated.

I have a territory with big amount of pixels which could be imaged as 2D array and the amount of pixels is constant .

Every element of it is a subarray with unlimited number of element representing a date of monitoring.

Each element of this subarray consist of 3 fixed element (YEAR, Day_of_the_year, reflectance_value).

[Image of a database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMmWi.jpg) [image]

To save some memory and space I can't just create a huge array, besides with time the database will be overfilled.

So when I have a new sattelite image I want to create a new subarray.

I suppose to store this data base on disk in HDF5 format because I heard that it is very good at processing huge arrays (in the future I need to do some math operations with this base).

**1) The question is should I use NumPy arrays to handle with such base?**

**2) If not - how to handle these often updated data using python?**

I read that every time you append data to numpy arrays it is copied to memory, so it will be very slow to process such big database as mine.

Comment: Most HDF 5 Python libraries use numpy; most database interactions in Python do not use numpy. So you'll likely be converting to a numpy array anyway.

Comment: I don't understand why you would append. You read a subarray, write it to HDF 5, then some time later you read another subarray, write that to HDF 5, etc.